# Add an JavaAgent outside of a jar (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, javaagents

Is it possible to add an `javaAgent` to the `RunConfidurations` of a class in eclipse?

Everything I have found about adding a `javaAgent` uses a jar-file to add it but I would like to run an agent without having to create a jar-file everytime before running the project from eclipse.

I tried adding a `-javaagent` to the arguments tab in my `RunConfigurations` but that only gives me
`Unrecognized option: -javaagent`

Comment: Provide us the full arguments you're adding in the `RunConfiguratinos` tab.

Comment: Now I'm using `-javaagent:testAgent.jar` and it works because of loonytune's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing things up here, if you use a java agent, the agent MUST be a jar file with a special manifest, there is no way around that. The application you are running does not have to be a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to add the javaAgent option in the java control panel. and once you set this option to the required JAR file, then that JAR file will run once the JVM is loaded.

Comment: It worked for me to configure the agent in the `RunConfigurations`

Comment: Hi Raven, Could you please explain how you did it? I have the same requirement.